# How to assign and use array of imageViews using tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created arrays of imageViews in UIScrollView programmatically and made then user interacted by assigning them tap gesture. Now, I want to differentiate, which image view is clicked so that I can get images from clicked imageView. However, I was unable to assign them different tag. Here is my code. I am adding 15 images Views.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        originx = ((_imageView.frame.size.width+5)*i); //Calculate origin x for each image view.

    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originx, self.view.frame.origin.y+5, imageViewHeightWidth, imageViewHeightWidth)];

    [_imageView setBackgroundColor:[ UIColor colorWithRed:191.0/255.0 green:65.0/255.0 blue:78.0/255.0 alpha:0.5]];
    //_imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_imgArray objectAtIndex:i]];

    //Enabling user interaction for gesture.
    [_imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [_imageView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    //Tap Gesture enabled.
    _gesture =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTheImage:)];
    _gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    //Add a tap gesture.
    [_imageView addGestureRecognizer:_gesture];

    //Assigning the tag to image View.
    _imageView.tag = 200+i;

    //Adding image in to scroll view.
    [_gallaryScrollView addSubview:_imageView];    
}

 //Here i am getting same tag value for every imageView. i.e. "214".
-(void)tapTheImage:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"The tag value of imagView is%ld",(long)[_imageView tag]);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the significance of tags in the question.  A `UITapGestureRecognizer` will just tell you what view was tapped, won't it, so why do you need tags?  Also why are you using the instance variable `_imageView` instead of a local variable?

Comment: No need to set tag in this case. you can get imageview by recognizer.view!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `TapTheImage` method

```
-(void) TapTheImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    //Get the View
    UIImageView *tableGridImage = (UIImageView*)gestureRecognizer.view;
    NSLog(@"%d",tableGridImage.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a new object of UIImageView.
Change the line

```
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originx, self.view.frame.origin.y+5, imageViewHeightWidth, imageViewHeightWidth)];
```

to

```
UIImageView *_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originx, self.view.frame.origin.y+5, imageViewHeightWidth, imageViewHeightWidth)];
```